# use of session or cookie in django

Tags: python, django

i am  getting **exact_plan** value in my following view using request.POST[] method which is okay.

```
def subscribe_plan(request):

    exact_plan = Plan.objects.get(id = request.POST['subscribe'])

    exact_validity = exact_plan.validity_period
    exp_date = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(exact_validity)
```

but how can i use that **exact_plan** value in other view.If it is possible with session or cookie ,then how can set them in my subscribe_plan view and how can i use it in my following view

```
def payment_execute(request):
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    token = request.GET['token']
    exact_plan = Plan.objects.get(id = request.COOKIES.get('id'))

    exact_validity = exact_plan.validity_period
    exp_date = datetime.datetime.now()+datetime.timedelta(exact_validity)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `def subscribe_plan(request):` , store `request.POST['subscribe']` in session like :

```
request.session["exact_plan_id"] = exact_plan.id
```

Use it in `def payment_execute(request):` like :

```
if request.session.get('exact_plan_id'):
    exact_plan = Plan.objects.get(id = request.session["exact_plan_id"])
    # further implementation.
```